# Jquery tr loop not continuiing after first loop with expectation of single user input per time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to loop between rows with jquery. I have 3 html fields and i want each field to appear one after the other. This is working so far but my challenge is that after the last field appears, I expect the loop to start all over i.e the 1st field be shown again and repeat the loop. This does not happen. Any help will be appreciated and below is my code

```
<td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <h3>hi</h3>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Enter Your Information:</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div class="question">
            <tr id="qline1">
                <td>What is your full name?</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="named" onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="qline2">
                <td>What is your address?</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="address" onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="qline3">
                <td>Date of Birth?</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dob" onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

JS:

```
if (named) {
    $(namedresult).html(named);
    $("#qline1").hide();
    $("#qline2").show();
    var identify = false;

    $(addressresult).html(address);
    if (address && named) {
        $("#qline2").hide();
        $("#qline3").show();
    }

    $(dobresult).html(dob);
    if (dob) {
        $("#qline3").hide();
        $(".reset").named
        $("#qline1").show();
        var identify = true;//At this point, the loop should go back to the first line       //and start all over. This does not happen.
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are there `<td>` tags around your table?

Comment: Also, what is `$(".reset").named` supposed to do?

Comment: The $(".reset").named was something i added when i was trying to see if the field can be blank when returned. I mean after the third field is hidden, the first field comes again but with a value. But that is really not my issue. The issue is after the first field on the second loop and i submit, the second field does not come.

Comment: @Blazemonger, If i understand your question, the td tags are just normal html tags, they are data inside rows in my table.

Comment: Where is the loop you are talking about? When and how is the shown Javascript called?

Comment: I have not been able to figure out how to attach my code. however this is the part for the loop

Comment: while ( i < 3 ) {
if (named) {
 $(namedresult).html(named);
 $("#qline1").hide();
  $("#qline2").show();
alert(named);


  var identify = false;

$(addressresult).html(address);
if(address && named){
  $("#qline2").hide();
  $("#qline3").show();
}

$(dobresult).html(dob);
if (dob ){
    $("#qline3").hide();
     $("#qline1").show();
    var identify = true;
      
  }
}
}
}